# SQL Foreign Key - Multiples products in single id?

Tags: python, sqlite

Can someone explain to me how to do this?

```
Table "SC": id_sc - id_name - id_prod - qtd
Table "Name": id_name - name seller
Table "Prod": id_prod - name prod
```

Example:

```
Table Name: id 1 - name Ivan
Table Prod: id 1 - name Orange
            id 2 - name Apple
            id 3 - name Banana             

Table SC: 2 - Ivan - Orange, Apple, Banana
```

I need the SC table to have multiple products in a single ID. 
I can not do the relationship between the tables.

Comment: What are you storing in `qtd`? Mainly is `qtd` depending on `id_sc` or on each product?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't as such you would have a reference/mapping table (which is what SC appears to be).

For example consider the following :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS name;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS prod;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sc;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS name (id_name INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS prod (id_prod INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sc (id_sc INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, id_name INTEGER, id_prod INTEGER, qtd INTEGER, UNIQUE(id_name,id_prod));
INSERT INTO name (name) VALUES ('Ivan'),('Fred'),('Mary');
INSERT INTO prod (name) VALUES ('Apple'),('Banana'),('Oranage');
INSERT INTO sc (id_name,id_prod,qtd) VALUES
    (1,1,10), -- Ivan has 10 apples
    (2,1,9), -- Fred has 9 Apples
    (3,1,21), -- Mary has 21 Apples
    (1,2,33), -- Ivan has 33 Bananas
    (3,2,16), -- Mary has 16 Bananas
    (2,3,22), -- Fred has 22 Oranges
    (3,3,5) -- Mary has 5 Oranges
;
SELECT name.name ||' has '||qtd||' '||prod.name AS who_has_what FROM sc 
    JOIN name ON sc.id_name = name.id_name
    JOIN prod ON sc.id_prod = prod.id_prod
;
SELECT name.name, group_concat(prod.name) FROM sc
  JOIN name ON sc.id_name = name.id_name
  JOIN prod ON sc.id_prod = prod.id_prod 
GROUP BY name.id_name
;
```

So table SC maps a name to a product.

The results of the queries are :-

[image]

[image]

Comment: I understood but what I need is to store the SC with its unique ID and within that SC I will have the name and the products.
SC nº 232
Ivan - Apple - 10
Ivan - Banana - 02
Ivan - Orange - 03

SC 254
Fred - Banana - 25
Fred - Apple - 21
Fred - Orange - 20